# RMI client and server running in different jre versions

Tags: java, rmi

I have no RMI experience and have a basic question I seem not to find an answer on the internet.
We want to have RMI calls from a client running jre 6.X to the server running jre 7.X. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. RMI is highly interoperable.

Comment: So I just call the server the regular way, without any special options/handling? 
What if the client is run in jre7 and server in jre6?

Comment: You just do it. No special options required. It is interoperable both ways, all the way back to 1.1.

Comment: Sounds like a Nike commercial:)
Thx, I will try it.